# Android media player to play sounds

Tags: java, android

I have a few sounds for button clicks, I want to create a class where the activities create an object of this class and pass in its context into the constructor and the class simply plays the sounds. Basically, one class for all sounds used for all other activities.

I want to do this because, I don't want to duplicate the same code for sound for each activity.

I want to know if this is ok do so. anything I should know before doing this?

Comment: It is all up to you, you can make a class which contains _all_ of your assets not just sounds. Whatever makes it easier for you.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the `SoundPool` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html